# Deal with futures in a loop

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, slick, slick-3.0

I am working on a method that makes a query to the database and takes one row. This row has a column specifying the parent id if any. So, my method has a closure named "iterate" that do the same process if the last row has a parent and finally the method returns a Sequence of those rows. This is simple at first sight, but I have to deal with futures and that stuff and I do not have much experience with async programming. So. My question is:

**Is there a way to do this method right without the use of "Await"?**

```
/**
   * Returns all the parents of the given sector if any
   * @param childSector
   * @return
   */
  def getParents(childSector: ShopSector): Future[Option[Seq[ShopSector]]] = {
    val p = Promise[Option[Seq[ShopSector]]]
    val f: Future[Option[Seq[ShopSector]]] = p.future

    val parentsSeq: Seq[ShopSector] = Seq()

    f.onComplete( thing => println(s"Result from Iteration future: $thing") )

    def iterate(sector: ShopSector): Unit = {
      val query = for {
        c <- ShopSectors if c.id === sector.id
        p <- c.parent
      } yield p

      exists(sector.parent_id).map { exists =>
        if (exists) {
          db.run(query.result.head).map { parent =>
            println(s"Result parent: $parent")
            parentsSeq +: Seq(parent)
            iterate(parent)
          }
        } else {
          p success Option(parentsSeq)
        }
      }
    }

    iterate(childSector)

    f
  }
```

I am using Slick by the way. And notice that this method is not working well. It returns an empty Seq and I know it is obvious that this is going to return that. But the print works fine and print the right results. The thing is that I can't imagine a way to have a variable that doesn't "disappear" before all the futures are completed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Okay guys. The problem was so simple. As Ixx said, the parentsSeq collection is not mutable. I fixed it by using a ListBuffer and then by converting it to a sequence.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is here: `parentsSeq +: Seq(parent)`. This doesn't mutate the sequence, it returns a new sequence instead.

Comment: I know. But that's not the main problem here I think. I can try with a ListBuffer for example but the thing is that if I define the variable outside the clojure wich make asyncronous proccesses, that variable doesn't exists in the future, right?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the code works if you use a mutable collection, or a var and reassign to it. The future is by definition something that doesn't exist yet... when the onComplete callback is executed I think the updated collection should be available. This closure has a reference to the collection and when the futures finish it's updated.

Comment: You are right. The problem was the collection. I was thinking all the time that the problem were caused by the futures. Anyways... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way I think you also can map the actions itself. So you could create a sequence of actions (`query.result` is an action), which you build recursively similar to what you are doing with the futures, then create one single action for them `DBIO.sequence(actions)` and run this with `db.run()`, then you get one single future with a sequence of results.

Comment: The thing is that I need the previous result to check if I need to keep querying.

Comment: I know. When you map an action you get the result of the query, exactly like when you map a future.

Comment: It's just an idea, not sure if it works. If it does it may bring a performance improvement as you would be querying the db only once... the fact that you need one result as input for the next query would be somehow solved at db level... but I'm just guessing... also not a lot of Slick experience yet. Tell if  it works ;)